# C++ как вызвать внешнюю функцию с параметром - указатель на функцию и передать функцию класса

Tags: c++

Есть некоторая внешняя функция (не моя - системная) - xTimerCreate
Эта функция принимает указатель на функцию.
У меня есть некоторый класс foo, метод которого я хочу передать в виде параметра в системную функцию.

Тут уже писали что для вызова функции метода вообще говоря нужно два параметра - ссылка на экземпляр класса и ссылка на саму функцию класса.

Нельзя ли для конкретного экземпляра класса сделать некую обертку чтобы передать функцию класса в системную функцию xTimerCreate?

Функцию xTimerCreate я поменять никак не могу.
Или данный вопрос не имеет решения ?

```
class foo {
    int a;
    void bb() { a++;};
};

foo c;

void func1() {int i =0;i++;};
void (*pfunc) ();

void xTimerCreate( void (*argfunc)() ) {
    (*argfunc)();
};

void setup() {
    // pfunc=&c.bb;  -- ошибка
    pfunc=&func1;
    xTimerCreate(&func1);
    xTimerCreate(&c.bb);  // ошибка
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно можно, например:
void foo_obertka() {
    c.bb();
};

Проблема в том что у меня методов порядка 10 - неужели для всех придется по такой функции написать ?

Comment: Ну, в лямбду запакуйте... Зачем писать копии?

Comment: @test123: Каким образом вы собираетесь передавать лямбду туда, где требуется обычный указатель на функцию?

Comment: @test123 - напишите пожалуйста пример как это сделать, я не понимаю :)

Comment: Вместо вот этого вот pfunc=&func1; я предлагаю делать xTimerCreate([&]()=>{ func1(); }); xTimerCreate([&]()=>{ c.bb(); });

Comment: @AnT, а разве в плюсах оно не конвертируется всё к указателю на функцию? Даже Function<Void()> будет передаваться как указатель на функцию (*ptr)();

Comment: @test123: К обычному указателю на функцию конвертируется *только лямбда с пустым захватом*. А вам тут нужна именно лямбда с *непустым* захватом, чтобы захватить `c`. Конвертироваться не будет. Что вы имеете в виду под `Function<Void()> ` - не понял. `std::function` так передаваться не будет.

Comment: Значит я не понял вопроса... http://cpp.sh/9gvdb

Comment: @test123: Может я не понял, что вы хотели сказать. У вас в примере `c` так и осталась глобальной переменной, т.е. ваша лямбда ничего не захватывает. То есть вы просто предложили сокращенный вариант записи с оберткой и глобальной переменной. Это будет работать, но исходной проблемы не решает.

Comment: @AnT, Точно, она же умрёт в конце метода, и в лямбде останется ссылка на мусор... Действительно, об этом я не задумывался.

Comment: @test123: Дело не в том, что она умрет. Дело в том, что как только вы сделаете `c` локальной, ваш вариант сразу перестанет компилироваться. Кстати, ваш исходный вариант тоже не должен компилироваться  (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80e9499bdd3a2bf3). Если в лямбде написано `[&]` - то это уже формально непустой захват. Такая лямбда не приводится к указателю. Для компиляции вашего варианта нужно именно `[]`. Ваш сайт по ссылке использует какой-то дырявый компилятор.

Answer (score 2):

Если конкретный экземпляр класса доступен глобально (как в вашем примере), то задача решается простым созданием функции-обертки.

Если же такой глобальной доступности нет, то этот способ не применим. Решить эту задачу языковыми методами можно будет только через изменение коллбэк-интерфейса таймера. Ваш системный таймер случайно не позволяет вместе с указателем на функцию передавать еще и указатель на пользовательские данные? Если нет, то все плохо.

Зачастую привязку коллбек-функции к пользовательским данным можно сделать косвенно. Например, через получаемый коллбэк-функцией уникальный идентификатор таймера или что-то в этом роде. Но для того, чтобы говорить конкретнее, нужно знать больше деталей о вашем таймере.

---

Для FreeRTOS таймеров у вас есть "идентификатор таймера", который является указателем `void *`. Вот через него вы и можете передавать в коллбэк пользовательские данные. В самом простом варианте, при создании таймера делайте

```
foo c;
...
TimerHandle_t ht = xTimerCreate("name", period, reload, &c, bb_callback);
```

а функцию `bb_callback` реализуйте как

```
void bb_callback(TimerHandle_t ht)
{
  foo *pc = (foo *) pvTimerGetTimerID(ht);
  pc->bb();
}
```

Comment: Вот сама функция (мне еще надо будет вызывать функции аналогичные):
https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-timers-xTimerCreate.html
Как водится обходных путей нет :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас же в функции есть параметр `TimerHandle_t` - из него можно получить прикрепленный указатель на пользовательские данные:

```
class foo
{
    int a;
    public: static void
    On_Timer(TimerHandle_t const h_timer) noexcept
    {
        auto const param{::pvTimerGetTimerID(h_timer)};
        if(param)
        {
             auto & self{*static_cast<foo *>(param)};
             // ...
        }
    }
};

foo c;
TimerHandle_t ht
{
    ::xTimerCreate
    (
         "my_timer"
    ,    xTimerPeriod
    ,    uxAutoReload
    ,    reinterpret_cast<void *>(::std::addressof(c))
    ,    &foo::On_Timer
    )
};
```

Comment: спасибо, Вы написали static void
    On_Timer - это значит внутри я не смогу получить значение int a (а оно мне нужно). Или тогда надо будет все static писать ?

Comment: @ГайратВласов его можно будет получить как `self.a`